# Sorting algorithm for unpredicted data

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, big-o

Considering the fact that currently many libraries already have optimized sort engines, then why still many companies ask about Big O and some sorting algorithms, when in reality in our every day in computing, this type of implementation is not any longer really needed?

For example, self balancing binary tree, is a kind of problem that some big companies from the embedded industry still ask programmers to code as part of their testing and candidate selection process.

Even for embedded coding, there are any circumstances when such kind of implementation is going to take place, given fact that boost, SQLite and other libraries are available for use? In other words, is it worth still to think on ways to optimize such algorithms?

Comment: This is awfully broad for Stack Overflow, and "any comments" is not really what we do here. We provide concrete answers to clearly-defined coding questions. Your subject lends itself more to [Programmers.SE], a sister site ([info about the difference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82988) -- loosely described as "keyboard questions" here vs. "whiteboard questions" there). I suggest you look into posting there.

Comment: @Josh Caswell .. thanks! I am rephrasing my question.

Comment: Use whatever sorting facility your language provides. They are almost always better than what you would write yourself.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos. I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an embedded programmer, I would say it all comes down to the problem and system constraints. Especially on a microprocessor, you may not want/need to pull in Boost and SQLite may still be too heavy for a given problem. How you chop up problems looks different if you have say, 2K of RAM - but this is definitely the extreme.

So for example, you probably don't want to rewrite code for a red-black tree yourself because as you pointed out, you will likely end up with highly non-optimized code. But in the pursuit of reusability, abstraction often adds layers of indirection to the code. So you may end up reimplementing at least simpler "solved" problems where you can do better than the built-in library for certain niche cases. Recently I wrote a specialized version of linked lists using shared memory pools for allocation across lists, for example. I had benchmarked against STL's list and it just wasn't cutting it because of the added layers of abstraction. Is my code as good? No, probably not. But I was more easily able to specialize the specific uses cases, so it came out better.

So I guess I'd like to address a few things from your post:
-Why do companies still ask about big-O runtime? I have seen even pretty good engineers make bad choices with regards to data structures because they didn't reason carefully about the O() runtime. Quadratic versus linear or linear versus constant time operation is a painful lesson when you get the assumption wrong. (ah, the voice of experience)

-Why do companies still ask about implementing classic structures/algorithms? Arguably you won't reimplement quick sort, but as stated, you may very well end up implementing slightly less complicated structures on a more regular basis. Truthfully, if I'm looking to hire you, I'm going to want to make sure that you understand the theory inside and out for existing solutions so if I need you to come up with a new solution you can take an educated crack at it. And if the other applicant has that and you don't, I'd probably say they have an advantage.

Also, here's another way to think about it. In software development, often the platform is quite powerful *and the consumer already owns the hardware platform*. In embedded software development, the consumer is probably *purchasing the hardware platform* - hopefully from your company. This means that the software is often selling the hardware. So often it makes more cents to use less powerful, cheaper hardware to solve a problem and take a bit more time to develop the firmware. The firmware is a one-time cost upfront, whereas hardware is per-unit. So even from the business side there are pressures for constrained hardware which in turn leads to specialized structure implementation on the software side.

Answer (score 3):

If you suggest using SQLite on a 2 kB Arduino, you might hear a lot of laughter.

Embedded systems are bit special. They often have extraordinarily tight memory requirements, so space complexity might be far more important than time complexity. I've rarely worked in that area myself, so I don't know what embedded systems companies are interested in, but if they're asking such questions, then it's probably because you'll need to be more acquainted with such issues than in other areas of I.T.

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing is optimized enough**. 
Besides, the questions are meant to test your understanding of the solution (and each part of the solution) and not how great you are at memorizing stuff. Hence it makes perfect sense to ask such questions.